# Cross-domain GET request, difference between browser and localhost making the call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get, cross-domain

I attempt to make a GET request to an API from a locally hosted meteor app (`=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/`) and upon doing so I get the error:

"XMLHttpRequest cannot load [the-api-url]. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin `http://localhost:3000` is therefore not allowed access."

Yet when I paste [the-api-url] into my browser and hit ENTER, the appropriate API response is shown in my browser window (a little JSON object). I have read some other SO posts about cross-domain request issues, but I don't understand the solutions, or what the difference is between sending the GET from my code or from the browser. Can someone explain why this behavior occurs, and what the appropriate change to my code/design is? My existing code is as below:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: auth_ad_act_url,
  data: {
    ads_token: ACCESS_TOKEN
  },
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

EDIT:
I do a jQuery.ajax() of type "get" supplied with a URL, parameters object, and success callback function, and dataType 'jsonp' to deal with cross-domain requesting.

I posted new code. Now the error is that the response is not correct. (I know this because it worked from my browser, and that responsee lined up with the API documentation). The response is "Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: [https://host.com/apps/[my-app-id]/authorize_ad_account?callbac](https://host.com/apps/%5bmy-app-id%5d/authorize_ad_account?callbac)…" but it should be an object with the key 'url' and one other thing. I also get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" when I include 'jsonp'. But that incorrect response mentioned above still gets logged to console so I don't understand when that syntax error happens, or where.

Comment: [MDN Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Answer (score 0):

The *Same Origin Policy* does not include what you type into your address bar. If it did, you literally would not be able to access any website at all unless it was saved on your local machine!

In your situation, in order to get the resource that you need from jQuery's get, you'll either need to use a server-side proxy hosted on a matching domain, or since you're consuming JSON see if the API you're using supports JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility to get JSON Data with a cross-domain request. You have to use JSONP and define a callback method, which has to be in the call and in the JSON Data.

**Your request:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: auth_ad_act_url + "&callback=?",
    jsonpCallback: "jsonCallback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        // Do something with the data
    }
)};
```

**The JSON File on the external server:**

```
jsonCallback(INSERT_HERE_THE_JSON_DATA);
```

If you do not have the possibility to add the jsonCallback on the external server, check out [CORS](http://enable-cors.org).

Comment: The URL I am requesting is someone else's API, so I can't do anything with their code, like insert that jsonCallback. What's this proxy business mentioned above? I read briefly what that means but I'm not sure what it entails code-wise.